# AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed After some connections

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I have a `Spring-Boot (1.4.0)` application and I am using `springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail`.

I have a method annotated with `@Scheduled` to check my inbox every a certain period of time.

This is how I get my inbox:

```
private static Folder getInbox() throws MessagingException {
final String protocol = "mail.store.protocol";
        final String storeType = "imaps";
        final String email = "email";
        final String password = "password";
        final String connect = "webmail.company.com";
        final String folder = "INBOX";

        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(protocol, storeType);

        final Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        final Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect(connect, email, password);

        final Folder inbox = store.getFolder(folder);
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        return inbox;
    }
```

Then I have this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    @Override
    public void checkEmailCreateCompanyAndSendCsv() throws MessagingException, IOException {
    log.info("Checking e-mail...");
            final Folder inbox = getInbox();

            final Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
            final FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, false);

            inbox.getMessages();
            final Message messages[] = inbox.search(unseenFlagTerm);


.....
.....
}
```

When the APP is running everything works great but after some time (around 7 to 8 e-mail checks) it starts to thrown an exception:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.    at
>   com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:717)   at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)  at
>   com.opessoftware.crs.selfcertification.services.EmailServiceBasic.getInbox(EmailServiceBasic.java:183)
>     at
>   com.opessoftware.crs.selfcertification.services.EmailServiceBasic.checkEmailCreateCompanyAndSendCsv(EmailServiceBasic.java:50)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

If I stop the application and run it again the error disappears and the cicle starts again.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it.

I was calling the connection too many times and I was exceeding the connection pool of my e-mail server. So what I did is to define the `getInbox()` and the `getSession()` as `@Bean` and `Inject` them to my `EmailService`.

Now it creates the connection only once. It is working fine.